# A better way to rephrase a relatively long sentence

Tags: phrase-request

> Manuscripts submitted should not exceed the limit of 7500 words or 12 pages. Also, *authors are encouraged to arrange their manuscript in a manner that the number of the pages is even.*

Is it possible to avoid the use of "in a manner that ...." in this sentence? I'm looking for better/shorter alternatives to this sentence.

Comment: An easy fix: change `in a manner` to `so`: _authors are encouraged to arrange their manuscript so that the number of the pages is even_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace 'in a manner that' (which sounds odd to my ear anyway) with 'such that':

> Also, authors are encouraged to arrange their manuscript such that the number of pages is even.

You could shorten it even further:

> Also, manuscripts should have an even number of pages.

Or even combine the sentences:

> Manuscripts submitted should not exceed the limit of 7500 words or 12 pages, and an even number of pages is encouraged.